# Solving $\frac{z^4}{i^{15}+i^{80}}=-1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> So the equation is
> $$\frac{z^4}{i^{15}+i^{80}}=-1$$

I`ve tried to solve it by this way $$z^4+iz^4=-2$$ => $$(1+i)z^4=-2$$ then I multiplied both sides by $$(1+i) => z^4=-1+i$$ and got stuck. which formula I should use next to solve it

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that $i^{15} = i^{12}i^{3} = -i$ and $i^{80} = (i^{4})^{20} = 1$.

Then the proposed equation reduces to
\begin{align*}
\frac{z^{4}}{i^{15} + i^{80}} = -1 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{z^{4}}{1 - i} = -1 \Longleftrightarrow z^{4} = -1 + i
\end{align*}

Once you have reached the last equation, notice as well that
\begin{align*}
-1 + i = \sqrt{2}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\right)
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the DeMoivre's theorem.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

> $$z^4/(i^{15}+i^{80})=-1$$

$\displaystyle -1 = \frac{z^4}{1 - i} \implies -1 + i = z^4 \implies $

$$\sqrt{2}e^{i(3\pi/4)} = z^4. \tag1 $$

The easiest way to tackle (1) above is to compute any one of the $4$ roots.  Suppose that the root that you compute is $re^{i\theta}$.  Then the $4$ roots will be given by

$$re^{i[\theta + 2k(pi/4)]} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,3\}. \tag2 $$

The reason for this is that the **peripheral equation**

$$z^4 = 1$$

has the $(4)$ roots of

$$e^{i2k(\pi/4)} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$$

---

In line with [De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), one of the roots to (1) above is

$$(2)^{(1/8)} \times e^{i(3\pi/16)}. \tag3 $$

So, combining (2) and (3), the $(4)$ roots are

$$(2)^{(1/8)} \times e^{i[(2k\pi/4)  + (3\pi/16)]} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,3\}.$$

---

**Addendum**
Tips

It helps to develop instincts on when to use Cartesian coordinates (i.e. $z = x + iy$) and when to use Polar coordinates (i.e. $z = re^{i\theta}$).

Although the following has probably been repeated over and over, at MathSE, since this portion of my answer is *gravy*, I will repeat it here.

It is important to know how to convert Cartesian coordinates into Polar coordinates.

Suppose that you have the complex number $(x + iy)$, where $x,y$ are both Real numbers, and at least one of the two numbers is not equal to $0$.

Then, you should compute $~~~r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \implies r > 0.$

At this point, it is important to take a step back.  You are striving for an expression of the form

$$re^{i\theta} = r\cos(\theta) + ir\sin(\theta).$$

This implies that you want

- $r\cos(\theta) = x$
- $r\sin(\theta) = y.$

Because of the way that $r$ was defined, as $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and because of the identity $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$, you are guaranteed that there will be exactly one angle $\theta$, within a modulus of $2\pi$ that satisfies:

- $\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}$
- $\displaystyle \sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r}.$